# Joomla Site Migration - DB issue?

Tags: joomla

I'm having a strange issue here: I've migrated joomla site from server to other. I've also done db dump (previous server) and restore (new server). Changed configuration.php accordly and run all.

First, I receive a "blank page" but, more strange, when i log in into administrator section, I can't see menu content (like they aren't stored into db). Obviously I've checked and content are stored into db.

I've also granted priviledges for all db to user that run this joomla site, but nothing changes.

Any ideas?

PS.: Running onto an old version of joomla 1.5.7

---

This is what error log give me

```
[07-Oct-2013 12:39:28] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: options in /pathtosite/plugins/system/bot_speedy.php
[07-Oct-2013 12:41:16] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: keywords in /pathtosite/plugins/system/SEOGenerator.php
```

Comment: You could try updating your Joomla version to 1.5.26 for starters

Comment: @Lodder: taking into account that we will update all joomla version of our Joomla Sites, how could this resolve my issue?

Comment: @Lodder: ps.: If I save new menu, it result in a "ok" message but new menu isn't showed...

Comment: Well you do realise that you're a whole 19 versions behind the latest 1.5 release. During this time there have most likely been bug fixes, some that *might* help. It's always best to update first ;)

Comment: @Lodder: Ok, db content retrieval is working like a charm. Frontend still blank :(

Comment: are you getting any errors on the error log?

Comment: @Lodder: checked php error file and obtained just few notice (undefined variables). Maybe I have to turn off some components to see if they're messing up whole site

Comment: @Lodder: turned off component (even uninstalled) but still getting blank screen without errors... Dammit!

Comment: what version of PHP is your new server running? Have you ensured your *configuration.php* file variables are correct?

Comment: @Lodder: Yes, I'm sure: I've took a working site configuration.php and changed only db parts (and log_path and so on). We run php 5.3

Comment: hmm. you mentioned before that there were some **undefined variables** in the error log, can you please add them to your question as they might be important

Comment: Well these could be important as both are system plugins. Have you tried disabling them to see what happens?

Comment: @Lodder: already tried...No error in log and blank page :|

Comment: I'm running out of ideas here. It's hard to tell without seeing the site, backend etc :/

Comment: @Lodder: I perfeclty know that could be a specific issue but I've tried because if it was a general issue, maybe someone could help me. But it seems not to be ... :(

Comment: @Lodder: Almost forgot to thank you .... :)